# How to float a grid above another grid in XAML Windows8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, grid

I'm searching now for more than 15minutes to get a answer whit no succes.

My problem is that i want to float a grid above another grid.

Is this possible? if so how can i do this?

I tried to get my idea to sketch.

[image: My sketch]

Any code examples would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid><!-- This Grid acts as a container -->
   <Grid>
      <!-- This Grid would be on the bottom -->
   </Grid>
   <Grid>
      <!-- This Grid would be on the top -->
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps... :)